# Is there a way to obtain the file name of a clip using VideoClip.originalpath?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have having difficulty obtaining and printing the filename of a video clip that I am playing in my Unity project.

I have asked UnityAnswers and a few other forums but no one seems to know so I thought I'd try my luck here. I have been researching the Unity scripting manual but again there is not much to go on since I am not THAT experienced with unity. I already have a script that is used to handle the videoPlayer functions but I was creating a separate script which referenced the videoPlayer one. The only purpose of this script is to print the name of a video file onto the console.

```
  path = videoClip.originalPath;

        if(path != null)
        {
            print(path);
        }
    }
```

Bear in mind that I am not even sure that is the correct code to use. I was going to using `fileInfo` but I'm not sure that would compile anything.

Comment: ```videoClip.originalPath``` gives you the path location of your video ```Assets/1.mp4``` Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

`originalPath`returns the location of the video you are playing. To get the current video clips' name, just add `name` tag to it.

```
  void Start()
    {
        string nameOfVideo = vpClip.name; //vpClip is video clip, not video player component
        Debug.Log("name of the video : "+nameOfVideo);
    }
```

Comment: Im actually trying to get its original path because I want the selected clip to be passed into an ffmpeg command, but this actually seems to work well too. However I do have one question. I have an array to store a bunch of clips that are then added to the video clip source in unitys videoplayer component. But for some reason im having trouble  referencing the video clip to get their original path. So was using .getcomponent but that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: then instead of ```vpClip.name```, use ```vpClip.originalPath```

Answer (score 0):

```
        using System.IO;
        public class VideoManager : MonoBehaviour
        {
          public TMP_InputField videoName;
          public VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
           void Update()
        {
            if (videoPlayer.isPlaying)
            {
               videoName.text = Path.GetFileName(videoPlayer.url);
                
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While your code may explain how to obtain the file name, you did not address the question which asks how to do it with `VideoClip.originalpath`. If this is not possible, you should say so in your answer! Also, check out [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to learn how to better format your code.